# svn post-commit для определенной ветки jenkins

Tags: curl, svn, jenkins, tortoise-svn

Всем привет! 
нашла нечто подобное для билда в дженкинсе. и оно работает:

```
> # curl -X POST  https://myusername:551e08fbe02f9f455dd914c84fc525b7@jenkins.mydomain.com/job/myjobname/buildWithParameters?token=Eip3eeruaceecham9bauh7nei5veoyieleemielazai6ye8eeg
```

мне необходимо сбилдить проект для **определенной** ветки после каждого коммита в свн.
подскажите, пожалуйста, статью или что-то подобное, что поможет мне найти решение

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, вы можете найти в сети примеры таких хуков. Но, с точки зрения SVN, вам в hook скрипте достаточно вызвать команду [`svnlook dirs-changed`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.c.dirs-changed.html), проверить изменённые пути и если они включают в себя путь той самой определённой ветки, то уже вызвать `curl -X POST` как указано в вашем примере.

Я не помню дальнейшие шаги в Jenkins и под рукой нет виртуалки с ним. Но, скорее всего, вам там нужно создать специальный job который будет выполнять `svn update` рабочей копии (SVN working copy) с той веткой. Рабочую копию нужно получить с помощью команды `svn checkout URL-TO-BRANCH`. К тому job'у, наверное, нужно будет получить специальный токен. В вашем примере вызова `curl` есть токен `token=Eip3eeruaceecham9bauh7nei5veoyieleemielazai6ye8eeg`.

Comment: сделала так, как Вы говорите. нужно ли ещё что-то помимо всего прочего настроить в дженкинс? subversion, например

Comment: @kate дополнил ответ.

Comment: а дженкинс не знает команды svn update/ соответственно, чтобы дергать джоб, я должна все манипуляции с свном и определением ветки делать в хуке? а что же делает дженкинс?